# JavaScript: Scrolling and getting item position triggers error

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I'm checking if an element is visible at the bottom of the page to apply auto pagination with scroll. It works fine and ajax gets fired but I keep getting this in the log

```
allNews:418 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at isScrolledIntoView (allNews:418)
```

Here's the code and note that img#loader is not visible by default for sure

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (isScrolledIntoView("img#loader")) {
                var cur_page = parseInt($("#cur_page").text());
                var last_page = parseInt($("#last_page").text());
                $("img#loader").remove();
                if (cur_page < last_page) {
                    $(".blog_loading").css('display','block');
                    cur_page++;
                    $("#cur_page").text(cur_page);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/newsPaginate/<?=$lang?>/' + cur_page,
                        success: function (response) {
                            //getting data and append it here
                            $("#bottomLinks").append('<img id="loader" src="/images/loader.svg" style="visibility: hidden; display: block">');
                            $(".blog_loading").css('display','none');
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
            else {
                //console.log('no');
            }
        });

    });

    function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
    {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }
</script>
```

How to fix this to stop logging this to the console

Comment: I feel that you are not providing the entire snippet.

Comment: Please, provide the whole necessary snippet

Comment: Code updated with the whole JS code just removed the ajax code to make it brief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that the '*elem*' is not always on the page, you change the *isScrolledIntoView* function to this:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    if ($(elem).length) {
        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Make sure you get a good understanding of what I did